# python compressing multiple data using gzip or zlib

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

Suppose I have multiple data: say 3 python `array`s (or numpy `array`s) and 2 list of strings.

How can I store each of the data in compressed binary format within the same zip file?

I looked at the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/gzip.html and the examples just showed how to write a single data that use `gzip.open` to open a file, and `writelines` to write out the single data.

I am using Python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put multiple files in a gzipped file, use [`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) with a mode of `w:gz`. Then you can use the [`addfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.addfile) method to put serialized objects into it (using a `StringIO` as the fileobj).

```
import numpy
np_array_data = numpy.zeros(100)
list_of_strs = ['abc'] * 100

import io
import pickle

np_array_data = io.BytesIO()
numpy.save(np_array_data, np_array)
np_array_data.seek(0)
str_data = io.BytesIO()
pickle.dump(list_of_strs, str_data)
str_data.seek(0)
with tarfile.open('output.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as dest_file:
    dest_file.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo('np_data'), np_array_data)
    dest_file.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo('str_data'), str_data)
```

If you only wanted to put a number of numpy arrays into a compressed file, you could just use [`numpy.savez_compressed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed).

Comment: Sure! Although you'll need to think about who's going to be opening the files. If it's another Python script then I don't think there's any platform concerns - zlib is cross-platform. Just make sure you use binary mode when writing the file.

Comment: would it be possible for you to give an example of serializing a numpy array and a list of strings?

Comment: I will definitely do this, but I can't right now - running late. Sorry!

Comment: I can be a bit late. Also, I was wrong about the `wb:gz` - should just be `w:gz`

Comment: thanks for the example (I did upvote the example), but would it be possible for you to show how it can be done via writing it to binary files (instead of `npy` and `pickle` file formats) as I want to re-use the same data in other programming languages?

Comment: Well, both pickle and npy *are* binary formats; the basic approach (serialising into a BytesIO and then putting that into a gzipped tarfile) will work for any format. Picking a binary format is really a separate question.